# Show SQL errors of Spring-security in tomcat

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, spring-security

I got a web application using the spring-security framework. I setted up a database to store users and their roles, but tomcat gives the following error.

```
17-sep-2010 11:56:14 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
17-sep-2010 11:56:14 org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

Is there any way how i can see the errors that occurred? I couldn't find anything in the tomcat and mysql logs.

Im using tomcat 7.0.2 and mysql 5.1

**Update:**
Added log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
# log4j.logger.org.springframework.target=System.out
```

and web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

No succes yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is not about an error occuring at runtime in your application:

```
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

rather this is simply the [Spring framework's JDBC support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) logging the fact that it has loaded support for translating error codes native to each of these SQL databases which translate into Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy. No error has occurred in the log message here.

If you want to be able to log more information about what Spring is doing, etc., the framework [uses commons-logging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e743) and there are a number of ways to configure the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

I was using in my spring security something like
select * from USER ...

change for select * from user .. and it works

Answer (score 0):

The reason i was getting the above error is due to the fact that i had missed **1 as enabled** attribute in the first sql query and **u.username** attribute in the second sql query of the spring security config.

```
 <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <jdbc-user-service 
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, 1 as enabled from users where username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.user_role from USERS u, USERS_ROLE ur where u.sl_no = ur.user_id and u.username = ?"/>
          </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <b:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <b:property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <b:property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/" />
            <b:property name="username" value="SA" />
            <b:property name="password" value="" />
        </b:bean>
```

Hope this helps someone struggling with this error!!