# Getting Error : SQLErrorCodes loaded: Spring jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am getting below error when I am trying to insert row in database and also while calling prepared statement:

```
INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
07:05:53,727  INFO SQLErrorCodesFactory:126 - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

Also below is insert statement:

```
String sql = " INSERT INTO customer_Table (customer_no ,customer_name ,address_no ,phone_no"
+ " ,email_addr  ,customer_type_code ,city_code ,language_code ,input_user_id ,input_timestamp ,last_update_user_id ,last_update_timestamp"
                    + ")    VALUES ( '"
                    + customerNumber2
                    + "' ,UPPER('"
                    + getTrimmedString(customerName,300)
                    + "') , '"
                    + addSeqNum2
                    + "'"
                    + ",'"
                    + processForNull(getTrimmedString(helperObject.getData().getVisitPhone(),30))
                    + "','"
                    + processForNull(getTrimmedString(helperObject.getData()
                            .getVisitEmailAddress(),256))
                    + "','001','"
                    + helperObject.getCityCode()
                    + "', 'en','SYSTEM',SYSDATE+-1/24,'SYSTEM',SYSDATE+-1/21)";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
```

Because of this error code is not executing completely. I am also not getting full stack of error.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: This is not an error take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736933/show-sql-errors-of-spring-security-in-tomcat

Comment: yes I already checked out those. But the problem is after this insertion in table is not happening

Comment: @prachik did you figure out? I'm getting this log after an insertion too, but can't figure out why.

Comment: @prachik Were you able to resolve this? I am facing exactly the same issue

Answer (score 1):

1. Length of background parameter, exceeding the length defined by the field in the database
2. The data type of descendant parameters conflicts with the data type of the field in the database